# Calculate infinite sum $\frac{12}{5} + (\frac{4}{5})(\frac{12}{5}) + (\frac{4}{5})^2(\frac{12}{5})+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Calculate the infinite sum $\frac{12}{5} + (\frac{4}{5})(\frac{12}{5}) + (\frac{4}{5})^2(\frac{12}{5}) + (\frac{4}{5})^3(\frac{12}{5}) + \cdots$

I actually managed to work it out since posting. It was a part of a geometry problem I had mostly worked out. So here's what I actually ended up doing. I factored it as 
$ \frac{12}{5}(1 + \frac{4}{5} + (\frac{4}{5})^2 + \cdots) $ Then I assigned a variable $y$ to the infinite sum $\frac{4}{5} + (\frac{4}{5})^2 + \cdots$. So $y+1=5y/4$ Then I just computed $y$ to be 4 and computed the sum to get 12. The solutions manual says my answer is correct. Here's the actual problem for more context. [image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$...=\frac{12}{5}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n$$

Moreover, you should know that if $|a|<1$, $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k=\frac{1}{1-a}.$$
Then, if you set $a=\frac{4}{5}$, you'll get the result.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{12}{5} + \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)\left(\frac{12}{5}\right) + \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2\left(\frac{12}{5}\right) + \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^3\left(\frac{12}{5}\right) + \cdots=\frac{12}{5}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{4}{5}\right)^n\\=\frac{12}{5}+\frac{12}{5}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{4}{5}\right)^n=\frac{12}{5}+\frac{12}{5}.\dfrac{\frac{4}{5}}{\left( 1-\frac{4}{5}\right) }=4 $$

Comment: Be careful.  The term $$\frac{\frac{4}{5}}{1 - \frac{4}{5}} = \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{\frac{1}{5}} = \frac{4}{5} \cdot 5 = 4$$ so the sum is $$\frac{12}{5}(1 + 4) = \frac{12}{5} \cdot 5 = 12$$